# C++ forward declare inline function in namespace problem

Tags: c++, namespaces, inline, forward-declaration

I'm trying forward declare my functions in a namespace. But I get an error.
Let me show my .h and .cpp files first.

Header:

```
namespace DeviceList
{
     int GetIDFromType(NNBSSString type);
     NNBSSString GetTypeFromID(int id);
     void CNNBSSDeviceListAddDevice(NNBSSString& DeviceName, NNBSSString& Address, int DeviceType,
        __STRING__ DeviceNetName, __STRING__ DevicePath);
     void CNNBSSDeviceListRemoveSelected();
     void CNNBSSDeviceListRemoveCache(int index);
     inline void CNNBSSDeviceListAddressConnectionRespond(NNBSSString& deviceAddress, bool OK, NNBSSThread* thread);
     void CNNBSSDeviceListUpdate();
}
```

And Source file:

```
namespace DeviceList
{
    int GetIDFromType(NNBSSString type)
    {
        int m_id;

        if (type == _("USB Camera"))
        {
            m_id = NNBSS_EVT_DEVICETYPE_USBCAM;
        }
        else if (type == _("IP Camera"))
        {
            m_id = NNBSS_EVT_DEVICETYPE_IPCAM;
        }
        else if (type == _("Microphone"))
        {
            m_id = NNBSS_EVT_DEVICETYPE_MICROPHONE;
        }
        else if (type == _("DVR"))
        {
            m_id = NNBSS_EVT_DEVICETYPE_DVR;
        }
        else if (type == _("NVR"))
        {
            m_id = NNBSS_EVT_DEVICETYPE_NVR;
        }
        else
        {
            m_id = -100;
            NNBSSErrorShow("Given DeviceType was wrong while getting int from NNBSSString!", 100);
        }

        return m_id;
    }

    NNBSSString GetTypeFromID(int id)
    {
        // Has to be given by using GetIDFromEnum

        NNBSSString m_type;

        switch (id)
        {
        case NNBSS_EVT_DEVICETYPE_USBCAM:
            m_type = _("USB Camera");
            break;
        case NNBSS_EVT_DEVICETYPE_IPCAM:
            m_type = _("IP Camera");
            break;
        case NNBSS_EVT_DEVICETYPE_MICROPHONE:
            m_type = _("Microphone");
            break;
        case NNBSS_EVT_DEVICETYPE_DVR:
            m_type = _("DVR");
            break;
        case NNBSS_EVT_DEVICETYPE_NVR:
            m_type = _("NVR");
            break;
        default:
            NNBSSErrorShow("Given DeviceType was wrong while getting NNBSSString from int!", 100);
            break;
        }

        return m_type;
    }

    void CNNBSSDeviceListAddDevice(NNBSSString& DeviceName, NNBSSString& Address, int DeviceType,
        __STRING__ DeviceNetName = __STRING__(), __STRING__ DevicePath = __STRING__())
    {
        SCNNBSSDeviceParameters params;
        params.DeviceName = DeviceName;
        params.Address = Address;
        params.DeviceType = DeviceType;
        params.DeviceNetName = DeviceNetName;
        params.DevicePath = DevicePath;

        SCNNBSSDeviceParametersList.emplace_back(params);

        {
            CNNBSSHardwareCheckCameraConnection* p_CNNBSSHardwareCheckCameraConnection =
                new CNNBSSHardwareCheckCameraConnection(Address);
            p_CNNBSSHardwareCheckCameraConnection->Run();
        }

        // Update all pages that have Device List active
        for (int c = 0; c < (int)m_NNBSSContentPanelList.size(); c++)
        {
            int pageID = c - 1;
            pageID < 0 ? pageID = 0 : pageID = c - 1;

            if (CNNBSSDeviceListAddressHandle(m_NNBSSContentPanelList[c])->_IsCreated)
            {
                CNNBSSDeviceListAddressHandle(m_NNBSSContentPanelList[c])->_RecreateList();
            }
        }
    }

    void CNNBSSDeviceListRemoveSelected()
    {
        if (CNNBSSDeviceListAddressHandle(CNNBSSControlPanelAddressHandle()->_GetCurrentContentPanel())->_IsCreated)
        {
            CNNBSSDeviceListAddressHandle(CNNBSSControlPanelAddressHandle()->_GetCurrentContentPanel())
                ->_RemoveSelectedFromList();
        }

        // Update all pages that have Device List active
        for (int c = 0; c < (int)m_NNBSSContentPanelList.size(); c++) {
            int pageID = c - 1;
            pageID < 0 ? pageID = 0 : pageID = c - 1;

            if (CNNBSSDeviceListAddressHandle(m_NNBSSContentPanelList[c])->_IsCreated)
            {
                CNNBSSDeviceListAddressHandle(m_NNBSSContentPanelList[c])->_RecreateList();
            }
        }
    }

    void CNNBSSDeviceListRemoveCache(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0)
        {
            index = 0;
        }

        if (SCNNBSSDeviceParametersList.size() < index)
        {
            index = (int)SCNNBSSDeviceParametersList.size();
        }

        auto itr = SCNNBSSDeviceParametersList.begin();
        std::advance(itr, index);

        if (itr != SCNNBSSDeviceParametersList.end())
        {
            SCNNBSSDeviceParametersList.erase(itr);
        }
    }

    void CNNBSSDeviceListAddressConnectionRespond(NNBSSString& deviceAddress, bool OK, wxThread* thread)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < (int)SCNNBSSDeviceParametersList.size(); c++)
        {
            if (SCNNBSSDeviceParametersList[c].Address == deviceAddress)
            {
                if (OK)
                {
                    SCNNBSSDeviceParametersList[c].DeviceConnectionStatus = NNBSS_DEVICE_CONNECTION_STATUS_STRING_ONLINE;
                }
                else
                {
                    SCNNBSSDeviceParametersList[c].DeviceConnectionStatus = NNBSS_DEVICE_CONNECTION_STATUS_STRING_UNKNOWNERROR;
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        // Update all pages that have Device List active
        for (int c = 0; c < (int)m_NNBSSContentPanelList.size(); c++)
        {
            int pageID = c - 1;
            pageID < 0 ? pageID = 0 : pageID = c - 1;

            if (CNNBSSDeviceListAddressHandle(m_NNBSSContentPanelList[c])->_IsCreated)
            {
                CNNBSSDeviceListAddressHandle(m_NNBSSContentPanelList[c])->_RecreateList();
            }
        }

        // Delete thread
        thread->Delete();
        delete thread;
    }

    void CNNBSSDeviceListUpdate()
    {// Whenever a USB device is connected, this function will be called automatically
        {
            std::vector<__STRING__> currentDevices, currentDevicePaths;
            CNNBSSHardwareAddressHandle()->GetConnectedUSBCameraList(currentDevices, currentDevicePaths);
            
        // Update all pages that have Device List active
        for (int c = 0; c < (int)m_NNBSSContentPanelList.size(); c++)
        {
            int pageID = c - 1;
            pageID < 0 ? pageID = 0 : pageID = c - 1;

            if (CNNBSSDeviceListAddressHandle(m_NNBSSContentPanelList[c])->_IsCreated)
            {
                CNNBSSDeviceListAddressHandle(m_NNBSSContentPanelList[c])->_RecreateList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I remove inline keyword before CNNBSSDeviceListAddressConnectionRespond function, compiler throws an error though for others compiler does not do the same. I wonder, why others works without inline but not CNNBSSDeviceListAddressConnectionRespond function?

Additionally, the complete error message:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found  NNBSS   NNBSS\Build\Debug\NNBSS.exe 1   
Error   LNK2005 "void __cdecl DeviceList::CNNBSSDeviceListAddressConnectionRespond(class NNBSSString &,bool,class NNBSSThread *)" (?CNNBSSDeviceListAddressConnectionRespond@DeviceList@@YAXAEAVNNBSSString@@_NPEAVNNBSSThread@@@Z) already defined in ClassManager.obj NNBSS   NNBSS\Build\Thread.obj  1
```

I use include guards.
And my header file is included by over 128 files.

If anything's missing here, let me know

Comment: please incldue the complete error message in the question. Does your header have include guards? Do you include it in more than one source?

Comment: Updated, is it enough?

Comment: How come the `inline` function is not defined in the header file where `inline` functions go?

Comment: Now it's too much. Are the internals of all those functions necessary to show the problem?

Comment: Be a bit clear, please. It seems it's kind of bug, already.

Comment: Pete Becker, otherwise they say "It's not clear, show it all"

Comment: read about [mcve]. It is all explained there. The code posted should be enough to reproduce the problem but not more. If you get the issue by including the header in >128 files then likely you can get the same error by including in 2 files only, or perhaps 1 is enough. The details of the definitios on the other hand are not relevant. Actually currently its not possible to say what is needed or not, because with the code you did post one cannot reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using VS2019. I had the same problem and as internet says we're not alone. So, it's a bug that will be fixed once you rebuild the project.